# Save and load structure array MATLAB

Tags: matlab, structure, mat-file

I am trying to save and load structure arrays in a MAT-file, but the structure array keeps changing every time I reload it. If save the following and reload it, it keeps adding struct in front.

```
struct.field1
struct.field2

save data.mat struct

struct = load('data.mat');
```

I know that this is happening because I load the file in a variable which makes it a struct and that it won't if I use only:

```
load('data.mat')
```

However I am calling the load command within a function and therefore I cannot use this. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this, so that I don't get:

```
struct.struct.struct.struct.struct.field1;
struct.struct.struct.struct.struct.field2;
```

after couple of times reloading the data.mat file, but just this:

```
struct.field1;
struct.field2;
```

Kind regards,

Romano

Comment: You mean that you don't know the name of the variable that will be loaded via the `load` command?

Comment: I do know the name, because I saved it myself, but I do not know how to solve not getting struct.struct.struct.struct. etc...

Comment: Then why can't you simply have `load('data.mat','structure_name')` in the function and return `structure_name`? Why do you even have to assign it to a variable?

Comment: Because just simple     load('data.mat');  does not work inside a function. But     load('data.mat','structure_name'); works. Thank you ;)

Comment: `load('data.mat')` works inside a function as well, FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid adding deeper nested structs you could choose to save all fields as individual variables using the content option *-struct*

```
MystructName.field1 = 0
MystructName.field2 = 1

save('data.mat', '-struct', 'MystructName')
```

Then load the data to a variable and I'll see that the structure hasn't changed

```
MyStructName = load('data.mat')
MyStructName = 
    field1: 0
    field2: 1
```

Ps. Perhaps this is only in your example, but naming your struct to `struct` is bad since it overwrites the Matlab built-in function named `struct`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Yes piece of code is just an example.